# retrieve the params of date in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I need to get the params of date in controller. In my view page I have 
<%= f.date_select :due_date %>. In my controller I need to retrieve it and pass the selected date to another controller.. How will I do it..?

def create
@task = Task.new(params[:task])
@task.save
redirect_to(calenders_path(params[:due_date])) 
end

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= redirect_to :controller => 'calenders', :action => "show", :due-date => params[:due_date] %>
```